# Tensorflow's asymmetric padding assumptions

Tags: tensorflow, padding, caffe, convolution

Why has TensorFlow chosen to prefer padding on the bottom right?

With `SAME` padding, to me it would feel logical to start the kernel's center anchor at the first real pixel. Due to the use of asymmetric padding, this results in a discrepancy with some other frameworks. I do understand that asymmetric padding in principle is good because otherwise one would be left with an unused padding row/column.

If TensorFlow would have given presedence to padding on the left and top, it would do convolutions and weights the same as `Caffe/cudnn/$frameworks`, and weight conversion would be compatible regardless of padding.

[image: TF gives bottom- and right- padding precedence]

Code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

tf.enable_eager_execution()

def conv1d_tf(data, kernel_weights, stride):
    filters = np.reshape(kernel_weights, [len(kernel_weights), 1, 1])
    out = tf.nn.conv1d(
        value=data,
        filters=filters,
        stride=stride,
        padding='SAME',
        data_format='NCW',
        )
    return out


def conv1d_pytorch(data, kernel_weights, stride):
    filters = np.reshape(kernel_weights, [1, 1, len(kernel_weights)])
    kernel_size = len(kernel_weights)
    size = data.shape[-1]
    def same_padding(size, kernel_size, stride, dilation):
        padding = ((size - 1) * (stride - 1) + dilation * (kernel_size - 1)) //2
        return padding
    padding = same_padding(size=size, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, dilation=0)
    conv = nn.Conv1d(
        in_channels=1,
        out_channels=1,
        kernel_size=kernel_size,
        stride=stride,
        bias=False,
        padding=padding,
        )
    conv.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.from_numpy(filters))
    return conv(torch.from_numpy(data))


data = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 4]]], dtype=np.float32)
kernel_weights = np.array([0, 1], dtype=np.float32)
stride = 2

out_tf = conv1d_tf(data=data, kernel_weights=kernel_weights, stride=stride)
out_pytorch = conv1d_pytorch(data=data, kernel_weights=kernel_weights, stride=stride)

print('TensorFlow: %s' % out_tf)
print('pyTorch: %s' % out_pytorch)
```

Output:

```
TensorFlow: tf.Tensor([[[2. 4.]]], shape=(1, 1, 2), dtype=float32)
pyTorch: tensor([[[1., 3.]]], grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
```

Comment: This does not answer your question, but this is not the only case where frameworks differ in padding (and incompatibilities don't only apply between TF and other frameworks)

Comment: Etarion: interesting! Elaborate?

Comment: One example I know is that Caffe and Apple's Metal Performance Shaders behave differently when you apply 3x3 pooling with stride 2 on a feature map with even sizes and no padding (at least you say you want no padding) ... Caffe acts like there's an implicit pixel of padding on the right/bottom side and produces a feature map that is one pixel larger than the one MPS produces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for historical compatibility reasons with previous (non-public) frameworks. It is unfortunate that the definitions aren't clearer, since it's a common stumbling block when porting between different libraries.